# Python equivalent of select * from a where account_id in (select account_id from b)

Tags: python, pandas

As the title suggests. I come from an SQL background was looking for the best way of doing this.

```
c = a.account_id.isin(b.account_id).astype(bool) 
a[c]
```

Is the above the most efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, but we can put them into on row , and you do not need to convert the `isin` out put as bool, since it is already bool type data

```
a[a.account_id.isin(b.account_id)]
```

Comment: I see. Thanks, what if I want to find everyone account_id that is in A but not in B?

Comment: @Mobix a[~a.account_id.isin(b.account_id)] adding ~  :-)

Comment: Damn that's slick. Also, I've done quite a few data analysis in Python courses and not a single one mentioned this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mobix ah, yw :-) and happy coding ~

Answer (score 0):

I’m not an expert but I think that .isin is a string operation and is generally slower than pandas slice operations.
I think an easier way to do this is

Edit:
Set index to id for a and b and use .loc:

```
a.set_index('id',inplace=True)
b.set_index('id',inplace=True)
a.loc[b.index]
```

Comment: That doesn't quite get you there. `a.account_id==b.account_id` only makes sense in pandas if `a` and `b` are DataFrames that are indexed the same way, and even then it will only select the indices where the `account_id` values match. The sample code suggests the OP is looking for rows of `a` where the value of `account_id` can be found in the set of values `b.account_id`.